# Typescript mapped type issue

Tags: typescript, type-conversion

I am trying to get a mapped type from a nested object. I need to get the keys of the object chained by a dot. So if the object looks like this:

```
{a: {b: 'c'}, d: 'asdf'}
```

I should get `'a.b' | 'd'` from the type.
I did this, and it's working:

```js
type ITranslationKeys<T> = {
  [key in keyof T]: key extends string ? (T[key] extends string ? key : `${key}.${ITranslationKeys<T[key]>}`) : never;
}[keyof T];

const value = {a: {b: 'c'}, d: 'asdf'} as const;
    
type TValue = ITranslationKeys<typeof value>;
```

But as you can see I have to check that key extends string or `${key}` in the else clause would fail as symbol cannot be assigned to string. Is there any other way of doing this without the `key extends string ? ... : never` part?

I have also tried extending T: `T extends Record<string,any>` but didn't work.

The error:

```
TS2322: Type 'key' is not assignable to type 'string | number | bigint | boolean | null | undefined'.
  Type 'keyof T' is not assignable to type 'string | number | bigint | boolean | null | undefined'.
    Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'string | number | bigint | boolean | null | undefined'.
      Type 'symbol' is not assignable to type 'string | number | bigint | boolean | null | undefined'.
```

Typescript 4, but if it's only possible in TS5 just let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with some basics of intersection. Intersection with primitive types is their mathematical intersection, which means that the result is the elements that are in both sets (types).

`number` and the union have nothing in common:

```
// never
type Case1 = ('a' | 'b' | 'c') & number
```

`string` is the supertype for any string, a.k.a any string and the union of strings is a subset of `string`, and the intersection will be the union itself, since `string` includes any string:

```
// 'a' | 'b' | 'c'
type Case2= ('a' | 'b' | 'c') & string;
```

Now, let's make the union contain some numbers along with strings:

```
// 3
type Case3 = ('a' | 'b' | 3) & number
// 'a' | 'b'
type Case4 = ('a' | 'b' | 3) & string
```

We can conclude that by using intersection we can retrieve desired values:

```
type A = {
  1: 'a';
  b: 'b';
};
// 'b'
type Case2 = keyof A & string;
```

Let's modify the mapped type then:

```
type ITranslationKeys<T> = { // no error
    [K in keyof T & string]: 
    T[K] extends string
    ? K
    : `${K}.${ITranslationKeys<T[K]>}`
}[keyof T & string];
```

Alternatively, we could use [Extract](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) built-in utility type that only returns the members of the first parameter that extend the second one:

```
type ITranslationKeys<T> = {
  [K in Extract<keyof T, string>]: T[K] extends string
    ? K
    : `${K}.${ITranslationKeys<T[K]>}`;
}[Extract<keyof T, string>];
```

Comment: That works, thank you. I was close to that, but I still don't know why if I create a new type `type AKeys = keyof typeof value` it only returns a intersection of strings. Why is it then crying about other types?

Comment: I suspect that `value` has only string keys and even if you write `T extends Record<string, any>` it doesn't mean that it will only have the string keys, it still can have any other keys

Comment: Yes, makes sense now that you say it. Thank you!